# Is it possible to extract a script from an MySQL database to create a copy of the tables on another MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, scripting

Is it possible to extract a script from an MySQL database to create a copy of the tables on another MySQL database which is located on a remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump either the structure of the tables, or their content, using the `mysqldump` command-line tool.

For example, to get a dump of the structure *(`create table` instructions)* of all tables of a database, you can use something like this :

```
mysqldump --no-data --user=USER_NAME --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST DATABASE_NAME
```

And, to get this to a file, instead of getting it to the standard output, you can redirect that output :

```
mysqldump --no-data --user=USER_NAME --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST DATABASE_NAME > dump-file.sql
```

If you also want the data of the tables, and not just their structure, do not use the `--no-data` option.

Then, on your other server, you can import the dump, using :

```
mysql --user=NEW_USER_NAME --password=NEW_PASSWORD --host=NEW_HOST NEW_DATABASE_NAME < dump-file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to extract a 'dump'?
yes of course. `mysqldump` utility is the general choice